# I cannot add appBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do a log in app, after finishing with the design I faced a problem where I could not add the function of going back to the old page, I searched and found about the appBar but I could not apply it.

`class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "LOGIN",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Email",
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            RoundedPasswordField(
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "LOGIN",
              press: () {},
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return SignUpScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`

Comment: What do you mean               by "it didn't work"?

Comment: You should add `Appbar` in `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use **Scaffold Widget** for displaying the **AppBar** try below code hope its helpful to you In Scaffold widget you declare AppBar  for Appbar refer ducumentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) :

```
class AppBarPage extends StatelessWidget  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Your Screen look like this-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

use Scaffold.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("MyHomePage"),
       actions: [
         TextButton(onPressed: (){
           Navigator.of(context).pop();
         }, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back))
       ],
      ),
      body:Body() ,
    );
  }
}
```

on onPressed event you can return to old page

Answer (score 0):

appBar can be used inside Scaffold.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('AppBar Demo'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            tooltip: 'Show Snackbar',
            onPressed: () {
             Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the home page',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```